# PayPal IPN notification is missing invoice parameter from new Virtual Terminal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We're using the IPN notification to update our Shopping Cart after receiving payments through the virtual terminal. We enter the Invoice Id but it does not come in the IPN notification. This happens *only* when using the new virtual terminal; the old one continues to work as expected.

Here are the distinct set of keys I receive in the IPN notification from the *new* virtual terminal:

- mc_gross
- protection_eligibility
- address_status
- payer_id
- tax
- address_street
- payment_date
- payment_status
- charset
- address_zip
- first_name
- mc_fee
- address_country_code
- address_name
- notify_version
- custom
- payer_status
- business
- address_country
- address_city
- quantity
- verify_sign
- txn_id
- payment_type
- last_name
- address_state
- receiver_email
- payment_fee
- receiver_id
- txn_type
- item_name
- mc_currency
- item_number
- residence_country
- receipt_id
- handling_amount
- transaction_subject
- payment_gross
- shipping
- ipn_track_id
- cmd

Comment: This is the sort of thing you should [submit to PayPal MTS](https://www.paypal.com/mts/).  You'll need to provide a screenshot or a video showing that you're adding the invoice ID, and then show the raw IPN you get back that doesn't include the value you entered as expected.  They should be able to verify whether or not it's a bug and get it fixed.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewAngell ... opened a ticket with them and they acknowledged it's a bug in the pre-release version of the virtual terminal.